# Matlab symbolic matrix as argument of function instead of individual components variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I want to export to file a symbolic expression that involves a matrix:

```
% M is a 2x2 symbolic matrix composed by M_1_1, M_1_2, M_2_1, M_2_2
M = sym('M_%d_%d', [2 2], 'real');
% s1 and s2 are scalar variables
syms('s1', 's2');
% Expression with M, s1 and s2
myExpr = M*[s1;s2];
% Store expression as matlab code in a function file
matlabFunction(myExpr, 'file', 'myExprFunc.m');
```

However, since the expanded expression is:

```
myExpr =

 M_1_1*s1 + M_1_2*s2
 M_2_1*s1 + M_2_2*s2
```

This creates a function with expanded input arguments (one per free variable):

```
function myExpr = myExprFunc(M_1_1, M_1_2, M_2_1, M_2_2, s1, s2)
...
```

With 20x20 matrices, this is nightmare. It would be nice to have a signature like

```
function myExpr = myExprFunc(M, s1, s2)
```

But nothing seem to work. The straigthforward approach `matlabFunction(myExpr, 'file', 'myExprFunc.m', 'Vars', {'M', 's1', 's2'});` returns an error because the free variables `M_x_y` must appear as arguments.
My current solution involves creating a wrapper function that assigns individual variables as `M_x_y = M(x,y);`, but it would be much better to get it done "the pretty way".

Do anybody knows a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use strings, e.g., `{'M', 's1', 's2'}`, when working with symbolic math. This has been deprecated and direct support for such usage is disappearing with each Matlab version. To achieve what you want, you can use:

```
M = sym('M_%d_%d', [2 2], 'real');
syms s1 s2;
myExpr = M*[s1;s2];
matlabFunction(myExpr, 'Vars', {M,s1,s2}, 'file', 'myExprFunc.m');
```

Comment: Wow... it was as simple as using variables instead of their string version. Works like a charm. Thank you! (Question edited to delete the unmatched bracket... just a typo).